# Use android as handset for pc?

Tags: android, bluetooth, skype

I have a nice phone with headphones (Google Pixel) and Bose 700.
The headphones are supposed to be able multiple sources but crash and get unstable towards the connection to the computer when I have booth connected (might be bad hard/software in the computer or the headset, unsure).

So now I would like is to get the audio (both in and out) from the computer to the phone in order to be able to be able to use Skype meetings etc.

Is there for instance some way to get the phone to identify itself as a bluetooh headset or something similar?
(The real need is that the outsound from the computer should be sent to the phone and the microphone sound on the phone should  be sent to the pc).

It would be perfectly okay to connect the phone with the computer with a cable as well.